# What happens if one of DC serial power fault?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

The circuit as this picture:

[image]

I create +/-5V dual rail powers for +/-Vs of OP-AMP with 2 power modules([IRM-03-5](https://www.meanwell.com/productPdf.aspx?i=677#1)).

*COMM* does not connect to GND.

What happens if the one of following fault occurs?

1. *Vs2_pos* open
2. *Vs2_neg* open
3. *Vs2* is 2V rather than 5V

Comment: nothing happens ... the power supply is not connected to anything

Comment: Hi @jsotola: I said in the article, this dual rail power connect to Vs+/Vs- of OP-AMPs

Answer (score 0):

As @jsotola says nothing happens, that's what happens. Except for answer 3, now you have a voltage difference of 7 V between Vs2_neg and Vs1_pos.

And +5 and -5 V is just a voltage potential of 10 V since COMM isn't connected to GND, meaning they only have reference to each other, effectively creating a single rail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Recently, my board was fault. I aware maybe fault is because *comm* was not grounding would be potential vulnerabilities, but I'm not sure.